Do I have to use a new background that's been republished under the 2024 rules?
The Character Creation rules has this ribbon in it regarding using backgrounds from older books:

Backgrounds in older D&D books don’t include ability score adjustments. If you’re using a background from an older book, adjust your ability scores by increasing one score by 2 and a different one by 1, or increase three scores by 1. None of these increases can raise a score above 20.
Similarly, species in older books include ability score increases. If you’re using a species from an older book, ignore those increases and use only the ones given by your background.
Also, if the background you choose doesn’t provide a feat, you gain an Origin feat of your choice.

The reason I'm asking this is the 2024 rules for the Noble background assign ability score increases to none of the scores that this character cares about. The character is a monk and the 2024 Noble background assigns improvements to Strength, Intelligence, and Charisma. However, being a noble is extremely important to this character's identity, so no other background really makes sense for him.
I have a character I created recently under the 2014 rules that uses the Noble background. Can I convert him to the 2024 rules for the purposes of race and class, but simply retain aspects of the 2014 Noble background and follow these rules for the purposes of assigning his ability scores and origin feat?
To clarify, I'm not asking if this will work mechanically (I can see no reason why it wouldn't). I am asking if the intent of this ribbon is to allow players to use backgrounds from older books that haven't been republished. For example, if you're playing in a game with everyone using the 2024 PHB, you can't be using the 2014 version of the Great Weapon Master feat, you have to use the 2024 version since that's been republished. But does that same requirement hold true with regards to backgrounds?

Have you discussed this with you DM?

@KorvinStarmast no because I'm intending to use this character in an AL game, so the DM is likely to be different each time. So I'm trying to figure out the most official answer for this.

I'd just mention that you can still be a noble in the story sense without taking the Noble background as such. I don't know your specific situation but it's completely legitimate to say something like "Bruce came from a noble family, but after his family was murdered he wandered the world for many years, learning the arts of fighting and stealth..." and using that to justify your background as a Wayfarer or Hermit or whatever.

Have you looked at the rules/handout for AL this season? WotC usually publishes season rules/limitations/guidelines for each AL season.  Referring to that might also improve the question.

@KorvinStarmast at the time of this posting, I could not identify any updated AL rules for the season that specifically referred to backgrounds in the 2024 rules.

OK, they might have moved that function over to DM's guild; the AL season rules used to be posted at Wizards of the Coast web page, dnd, but I have not checked in a while.

@KorvinStarmast I actually went and looked for it again after reading your comment, but I can only find rules dating back to March 2024. A friend of mine that I play with found updated AL rules with a publication date after that point, but I can't figure out where he got them. The WOTC boards seemed to indicate that they're posting them on Discord for...reasons? It's a separate question, but I genuinely don't know what they're doing with AL rule distribution; it sure doesn't feel like they're trying to make it easy.

@Pyrotechnical Wow, thanks for the update.  IN 2014 it was easy to find AL stuff at dndwizards. What is up with these folks?

Hey @Pyrotechnical here they are AL updated rules

@KorvinStarmast thanks the link! Alas, it seems they're still linking back to the forum post with links that folks were complaining about never being updated (i.e. they still refer to the March 2024 rules despite later rules being issued with a later publication date).

@Pyrotechnical Sorry, I guess my joy was premature.

The passage on choosing a background begins with the following mention:

You can choose any of the backgrounds detailed in chapter 4, and your DM might offer additional backgrounds as options.

In other words, if you're going to use anything other than the samples provided, you're meant to talk about it with your DM, at which point anything goes. If you are specifically adapting a character you have previously built with the 2014 rules, I would expect your DM to be flexible.
That said, I think it would be a mistake to consider the 2024 backgrounds as updated versions of the 2014 backgrounds. While the new PHB uses the same names, the archetypes they describe are much more specific. It seems quite reasonable to apply the rules for "Backgrounds in older D&D books" when porting a character from the 2014 rules, letting the player get the ASI and origin feat of their choice to better match what is already established.
PS: Nothing in the rules says you have to pick the Noble background for your character to be a noble.

Note that in the 2014 PHB, backgrounds were very open-ended, and included questions to ask yourself while establishing a rich backstory for your character with the help of your DM. That open-endedness was often at odds with the feature granted by the background. Someone with the noble background might have been disowned, yet their feature would claim that everyone treats them with utmost respect.
In contrast, the 2024 backgrounds are terse, and merely attempt to narratively justify a set of mechanical benefits. A noble is someone who had a privileged upbringing, which is represented by their bonuses to STR, INT and CHA and their three additional tool/skill proficiencies on top of History and Persuasion.

"Nothing in the rules says you have to pick the Noble background for your character to be a noble." ... this exactly illustrates my point that WotC missed the mark by tying ability scores to backgrounds....

@byMaelstromer This was also true in the 2014 PHB, which explicitly gave the example of two characters who grew up as street urchins, but one of them picking the Urchin background and the other one Criminal. The point is to pick a background that fits your character's skills and not get stuck up on its name.

But does that same requirement hold true with regards to backgrounds?
Yes, and no.  The Player's Handbook(2014) allows for custom backgrounds, even though WotC chose to move this to the DMG for reasons.  You can create your own custom background that functionally looks the same as the Noble from 2014, and then follow the rules for updating it to 2024 compatibility.  The Noble in 2024 is not awesome, with unfocused ability scores, a useless tool proficiency, and a sub-par feat. I would stay away from it

So you're saying to get around it via technicality?

@Pyrotechnical given that it's an awful design decision you should get around it by any way possible.

@SeriousBri Yes, that's the correct assessment.

"The Noble in 2024 is not awesome..." it is funny how this is true from a gaming perspective, while historically being a noble (and the privilege and advantages it gave) was generally considered a good thing.  Not saying that there weren't pressures and some insane family members (or family enemies) to contend with.  But the ability to eat on a regular basis and even study or pursue the arts was a big advantage.

@wakkowarner321 Not to mention being ablel to afford a weapon, a horse, and a suit of mail ...

@KorvinStarmast Yeah.  The Noble should be updated to allow for more starting gold as well as the CHOICE of which attribute increases you want (to represent what your character pursued since they had the luxury of free time).  AND the ability to make some kind of check to get more resources or use their status for favors.  BUT it also comes with some obligations the DM can impose WHENEVER they deem fit.


I am asking if the intent of this ribbon is to allow players to use backgrounds from older books that haven't been republished.

Yes, it's only for species and backgrounds that haven't been republished.
Exactly what that means might vary from group to group, e.g. there are alternate features for the PHB backgrounds published in Baulder's Gate: Descent into Avernus, to some groups these should use the PHB 2024 ability score adjustments and Origin feats, to others they would not.

Are there any citations you can provide to support this? The part I quoted about the feats I'm sort of accepting as some common knowledge that I'm guessing I've pulled from hearing discussions, but I can't find specifics that fully state this.
